# Is this possible? Scroll slides to key points, like vertical paging

Tags: javascript, scroll, paging

Lets say I've got a site with vertical "slides". Each of them take sup a large portion of the screen. Is there any clean way to add vertical paging to the scrolling? Such as, if one scrolls near a specific horizontal point on the page, the page will slide so that the top border of the section meets the top of the window exactly?

I'm looking to add something similar to the iPhone's "vertical paging" feature to web apps. How would I go about doing this, is there any clean way to do it?

Here is an example of the iPhone's vertical paging...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgCcSF2Ip64

(sorry for poor video quality, I couldn't find any other examples of vertical paging)

The site I've currently got looks something like this, with vertical panes that one scrolls to. But if I had the paging, when you scrolled, it would lock you towards the nearest vertical "pane".

http://www.nikebetterworld.com/

(also, Nike better world is an awesome site)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sencha touch allows for this feature in what they call a "carousel" follow this link to see a demo of it in action.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/

click "User Interface" then "Carousel", notice both vertical and horizontal scrolling. This uses panels, and is definitely better for touch screens, it's not very good for mouse interaction though. Anyways, these panels are very customizable. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're talking about touch interfaces versus desktop interfaces. If you're looking to achieve this on an iPhone, there are a ton of things you can glue and massage to achieve this.  http://jqtouch.com/ is a jQuery plugin with some nice hooks for mobile browsers.

You're essentially managing how and when X and Y can scroll. Paging would be container elements like a div or li. Feel free to add more thoughts...

Comment: I'm actually thinking more of "trackpad" use on laptops.

Comment: Well, outside of Safari I think you might have some struggles with that. Might consider learning mouse gestures (like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mouse-gestures-redox/), browser plugin?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to disable scrolling but catch the scrolling event and move the content accordingly.

Comment: Looking back, it seems like it would be bad for people who use mice.

Comment: yeah, you wanna provide some sort of fallack for people you cannot scroll easily, but i like the idea in general. there are just certain kinds of content that a better displayed in a contained managed way. you could also easily add support for keyboard or even provide buttons for navigation, or swipe gestures with mice. its all a matter of user education

Comment: Yeah, also, to give a better idea of the site I'm currently building, I've added a link above.